# How do I get Bootstrap spans to reflow in a different order?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Is it possible to have an arrangement of Bootstrap spans that follow the order LEFT SIDEBAR, MAIN CONTENT, RIGHT SIDEBAR in desktop mode, and MAIN CONTENT, LEFT SIDEBAR, RIGHT SIDEBAR in mobile mode?

Here's a jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/krishunt/3J2KC/ I've got the MAIN CONTENT span listed first so it will appear on top in mobile mode, but I can't get it to appear in the middle of the two sidebars in desktop mode.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4 main_content">
        MAIN CONTENT
    </div>

    <div class="span4 sidebar pull-left">
        LEFT SIDEBAR
    </div>

    <div class="span4 sidebar pull-right">
        RIGHT SIDEBAR
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Responsive Utilities Classes to hide\show different rows\elements. You can use `hidden-phone` and `visible-phone` classes to accomplish this.

DEMO:[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/3J2KC/1/)

Comment: Wouldn't you have to duplicate your content then?

Comment: @KrisHunt Yes, its not ideal, but it gets the job done. I'm sure there are other ways to accomplish this with clever CSS, but this is by far the simplest method if you are already using bootstrap.

Comment: Oh! I was thinking I'd have to actually duplicate content, but all I have to do is duplicate a line or two of code in the template. Duh! This is great, thanks!

Comment: Got it working on my site! That was dead simple! And painfully obvious now that I think about it!